# Magento 2 - All sales emails to same address (no emails to customer)?

Tags: magento2, email, sales-order, sales, customer-emails

When sending order confirmations, I wish to have them all go to a specified email address and disable them going to the customer.

Please note, this is for internal use, where everything is free and no legal requirements to offer invoices/etc.  I need to send data for the order and customer via this order email, formatted so that it can be captured by another system.

I found within **Magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php** on line 2501:

```
/**
 * Returns customer_email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomerEmail()
{
    return $this->getData(OrderInterface::CUSTOMER_EMAIL);
}
```

and then again on line 4045:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setCustomerEmail($customerEmail)
{
    return $this->setData(OrderInterface::CUSTOMER_EMAIL, $customerEmail);
}
```

Editing this works, in that I can redirect all emails to a static address (example@domain.com) but it also replaces the customer's email as it appears in the order to the same address (example@domain.com).  I still need to have the CUSTOMER_EMAIL value = the customer's email as I need to send that within the email as part of the email body.

Which is the right file to edit where the sending of the email is executed so I can change the address there?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK email address set in here

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php
```

`prepareTemplate()` method

But you can not create prefrence of this class as its abstract.

So what you can do is create prefrence of this clas `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php`

and with in `send()` method wrap your code before and after this code `$this->checkAndSend($order)`

what You can so is

```
$orignalCustomerAddr = $order->getCustomerEmail();
$order->setCustomerEmail($yourEmailAddr); 
//after $this->checkAndSend($order) this line below code
$order->setCustomerEmail($orignalCustomerAddr);
```

> Update as per OP requirement

For using $originalCustomerAddr in template you can add one extra array result in `prepareTemplate` method.

So just add one extra variable like this in `$transport` result set

```
    $transport = [
        'order' => $order,
        'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
        'store' => $order->getStore(),
        'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
        'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
        'orignalEmail'=> $orignalEmail
    ];
```

And in email template you can use this variable as `orignalEmail`

Comment: It worked great, except today I realised that I can't use {{var order.getCustomerEmail()}} inside the order email template to send the customer's email.  This is important as I need to push this email address to the other system.

So I either need help with another way to send to a fixed address or how I can get the variable $originalCustomerAddr into the email template.

Comment: @Kai check updated answer

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response, unfortunately, that led to an error that resulted in the email being unable to be sent.  Instead of the confirmation "You sent the order email." it returned "We can't send the email order right now." and no email was sent.

Comment: @kai were you get `$orignalEmail` variable in `prepareTemplate` method

Comment: Yes, I had done as you instructed in the section under "Update as per OP requirement".

Comment: how you get `$orignalEmail` in `prepareTemplate` method ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  My code looked identical to yours, except that I changed the name to match my variable $originalEmailAddr.

Comment: @Kai `$originalEmailAddr` is in  `checkAndSend` method so how you pass that varibale to `prepareTemplate` method